# nginx multiple sites not working too many redirects

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I am trying to add another site to my nginx server.
The problem is the server does not execute php for second site.

> This page isn’t working xxx.com redirected you too many times.

Been a week trying to fix the problem, im new to nginx as switched from apache.
Any help is appreciated.

default(site1):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

site 2 im trying to add:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/xxxs.com/html;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name xxxs.com www.xxxs.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri / /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    location ~\.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~/\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Both sites run wordpress.
When i try to open a text file on second site it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space  is important. These lines miss the space.

```
1. try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
2. location ~ \.php$ {
3. location ~ /\.ht {
```

The complete config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/xxxs.com/html;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name xxxs.com www.xxxs.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: By space @Ben is referring to the space in the OP example for the `try_files` between `$uri` and `/`

Comment: i still get error
currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: wow the wordpress i had added had corrupted files
thanks everybody for the help